# Rotating Ellipse Around Center

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to build a generic loading control. I have the dummy control all set up with the gradient and masking, but I'm finding when I actually run it in a window it appears to rotate slightly off kilter. If you drop the below code into a user control, then drop that control into a window you should see the behavior I'm describing. I defined RenderTransformOrigin, so I'm a little confused as to why it's still not centering the rotation to the middle of the ellipse.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SpinningGradient.LoadingControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SpinningGradient"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="300">
   <Grid>
      <Ellipse Stretch="Uniform"
               RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
         <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="noFreeze" />
         </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
         <Ellipse.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
               <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard>
                     <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                      By="10"
                                      To="360"
                                      Duration="0:0:1"
                                      RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                  </Storyboard>
               </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
         </Ellipse.Triggers>
         <Ellipse.Fill>
            <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="0.5"
                                 RadiusY="0.5">
               <RadialGradientBrush.GradientOrigin>
                  <Point X=".9"
                         Y=".9" />
               </RadialGradientBrush.GradientOrigin>
               <RadialGradientBrush.Center>
                  <Point X="0.5"
                         Y="0.5" />
               </RadialGradientBrush.Center>
               <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                  <GradientStop Color="Blue"
                                Offset="1" />
                  <GradientStop Color="Red"
                                Offset="-.5" />
               </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </RadialGradientBrush>
         </Ellipse.Fill>
         <Ellipse.OpacityMask>
            <DrawingBrush>
               <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                  <GeometryDrawing>
                     <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" />
                     </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                     <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <GeometryGroup FillRule="EvenOdd">
                           <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,100,100" />
                           <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="30"
                                            RadiusY="30"
                                            Center="50,50" />
                        </GeometryGroup>
                     </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                     <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Thickness="0"
                             Brush="Black" />
                     </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                  </GeometryDrawing>
               </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            </DrawingBrush>
         </Ellipse.OpacityMask>
      </Ellipse>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Set the Width and Height of the Ellipse to the same value, or bind one to the other. Or put the Ellipse into a square container.

Answer (score 2):

The UserControl below creates a very similar or the same visual result with a lot less XAML. The ratio between StrokeThickness and RadiusX/RadiusY determines the relative stroke width.

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Viewbox>
        <Path StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Path.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
                                To="360" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Path.Triggers>
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
            <Path.Data>
                <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"/>
            </Path.Data>
            <Path.Stroke>
                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.9,0.9">
                    <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="-0.5" />
                    </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Path.Stroke>
        </Path>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that even though your `Ellipse` looks like a circle, it is still stretching to the size of its container (or, more precisely, to the size of the `LoadingControl`). So, unless the said `LoadingControl` is contained within a perfect square, the `Ellipse`'s actual center point is going to be offset from the center point of the visible circle, either horizontally or vertically. And around that actual center point (rather than the apparent center point) the `Ellipse` is rotated.

@Clemens already gave you a handful of options to remedy this situation in the comments section, but let me quickly go over them:

- Set `Width` and `Height` of your `Ellipse` to the same value - this is limiting since you have to hard-code the size of your control
- Bind the `Width` to the `ActualHeight` of the `Ellipse` (or the other way around) - this gives you some extent of dynamic behavior, but things go bad if the target dimension constraint is smaller than the source dimension constraint (e.g. if you bind `Width` to `ActualHeight`, things go bad when your control is contained within a rectangle with its width smaller than its height - the `Ellipse` is clipped)
- Put the `Ellipse` in a square container - or more precisely, within a container that would always arrange it in a square

**I strongly recommend** the last approach, since it gives you full flexibility in sizing your control. Now I don't think there's a component shipped with *WPF* that could accomplish this task, but it is fairly simple to devise one of your own, and I guarantee from my experience, that it'll become a useful tool in your toolbox. Here's an example implementation, which is based on a `Decorator`:

```
public class SquareDecorator : Decorator
{
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        if (Child != null)
        {
            var paddingX = 0d;
            var paddingY = 0d;
            if (arrangeSize.Width > arrangeSize.Height)
                paddingX = (arrangeSize.Width - arrangeSize.Height) / 2;
            else
                paddingY = (arrangeSize.Height - arrangeSize.Width) / 2;
            var rect = new Rect
            {
                Location = new Point(paddingX, paddingY),
                Width = arrangeSize.Width - 2 * paddingX,
                Height = arrangeSize.Height - 2 * paddingY,
            };
            Child.Arrange(rect);
        }
        return arrangeSize;
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        var desiredSize = new Size();
        if (Child != null)
        {
            Child.Measure(constraint);
            var max = Math.Min(constraint.Width, constraint.Height);
            var desired = Math.Max(Child.DesiredSize.Width, Child.DesiredSize.Height);
            desiredSize.Width = desiredSize.Height = Math.Min(desired, max);
        }
        return desiredSize;
    }
}
```

Then you only need to slightly modify your control:

```
<UserControl (...)>
    <local:SquareDecorator>
        <Ellipse (...) />
    </local:SquareDecorator>
</UserControl>
```